# Strange errors after converting SceneKit sample code to Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, scenekit, swift3

I downloaded Apple's SceneKit sample code (fox.swift) and opened it up on Xcode 8 beta 6. 
It asked me to convert the code to Swift 3, which I did.

When I try to run the code on my phone I receive the errors:

> Value of type ‘SCNNode’ has no member ‘run’
>
> Value of type ‘SCNNode’ has no member ‘add’

Sample lines where the error occurs:

```
cameraYHandle.run(actionY)
self.cameraYHandle.add(cameraYAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

This leads me to three questions:

1) Are the functions 'run' and 'add' gone on SCNNode for Swift 3?

2) If so, what should I replace them with?

3) If so, if so, why didn't Xcode's converter handled them already?

Thank you for your time :)

PS.: It runned well for Mac using Xcode 7.3.

Comment: It should be `runAction(actionY)` and `addAnimation(cameraYAnimation, forKey: nil)`

Comment: Thank you! You're right, also `play` translates to `playAudio`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dan commented, these translations resulted in a code without errors:

`run` => `runAction`

`add` => `addAnimation`

`play` => `playAudio`

so,

`cameraYHandle.run(actionY)` becomes `cameraYHandle.runAction(actionY)`

and so on.

Thank you, Dan.